# Doubts about downvote

Tags: discussion

I've just [asked a question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/8061/2587) on this site and it got downvoted. Which is fine, but I genuinely don't understand what problem there might be, if any, to cause a downvote.

I might be missing something, after all I'm not a regular here, so can someone enlighten me and help me understand what's wrong with it so that I can fix it?

Comment: Your question seems fine to me.  Votes are anonymous by design; don't sweat the drive-bys.

Comment: Could just be someone going for [critic].

Comment: @MatthewRead Thanks. I wasn't sweating lol I wasn't even that worried. Just wondering if I could further improve it. :)

Comment: The only possible reason I can think of for downvoting this Q is topicality. It somehow doesn't appear music-specific. I disagree with this reason, but I can understand it. ... Just a wild guess, but I am sometimes intuitive about such things.